# Why is the CSS module styling not being applied on the first component in a list of react child components?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, css-modules

I'm using Gatsby to build this e-commerce site and primarily styling my React components with CSS modules (and a little bit Material-UI for some pieces).

My site works as intended in development but in production after I deploy the site to Netlify, the CartItem (child component) inside my Cart (parent component) loses it's styling when I refresh the page OR when I visit that page's url (e.g. www.mywebsite.com/cart) from an outside website and on redirects to that URL.

**But what's interesting is that this ONLY happens to the first CartItem component in the list (or if there's only one CartItem). The styling for all subsequent CartItems works properly.**

**Here, my Cart renders a list of CartItems if any exist:**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "gatsby";

import CartContext from "../contexts/CartContext";
import CartItem from "./CartItem";
import Checkout from "./Checkout";
import styles from "./Cart.module.scss";

const CartPage = () => {
  const { cart } = useContext(CartContext);

  const { cartHeader, basket } = styles;

  const renderCartItems = () => {
    if (cart && cart.length !== 0) {
      return cart.map(({ sku, quantity, name, size, price, image, slug }) => {
        return (
          <CartItem
            key={sku}
            sku={sku}
            quantity={quantity}
            name={name}
            size={size}
            price={price}
            image={image}
            slug={slug}
          ></CartItem>
        );
      });
    }

    return (
      <div>
        Your cart is empty! Continue shopping{" "}
        <Link style={{ color: "#9c7451", fontWeight: "bold" }} to="/store/">
          here.
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={cartHeader}>
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
      </div>
      <div className={basket}>{renderCartItems()}</div>
      {cart && cart.length !== 0 && <Checkout />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartPage;
```

**Here is the CartItem:**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import Img from "gatsby-image";

import CartContext from "../contexts/CartContext";
import styles from "./CartItem.module.scss";

const CartItem = props => {
  const { onRemoveFromCart } = useContext(CartContext);

  const {
    item,
    section1,
    itemImage,
    productInfo,
    removeItem,
    section2,
  } = styles;

  return (
    <div className={item}>
      <div className={section1}>
        <Img
          className={itemImage}
          fluid={props.image.childImageSharp.fluid}
          alt={props.name}
        />
        <div className={productInfo}>
          <h4>{props.name}</h4>
          <div
            className={removeItem}
            onClick={() => onRemoveFromCart(props.sku)}
            onKeyDown={() => onRemoveFromCart(props.sku)}
            role="button"
            tabIndex={0}
          >
            Remove
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={section2}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartItem;
```

**Here is the CSS module for CartItem**

```
.item {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
  padding-top: 30px;

  .section1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1.25fr;
    grid-gap: 1rem;

    .itemImage {
      &:hover {
        opacity: 0.8;
      }
    }

    .productInfo {
      padding-top: 1.85rem;

      h4 {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .removeItem {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 0.5rem;
        padding: 2px 2px 2px 0;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;

        &:hover {
          opacity: 0.8;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .section2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .item {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;

    .section1 {
      grid-gap: 2rem;

      .productInfo {
        padding-top: 0;
      }
    }

    .section2 {
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: flex-start;

      .total {
        text-align: right;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the website if any of you want to test it out: https://www.roxannecamilledesigns.com

**To reproduce the issue:**

1. Go to store section, click on item and add to cart
2. Navigate to Cart either from the Navbar or Popup that shows when you add item
3. See that CartItem styling works perfectly
4. Refresh page and see that the CartItem goes unstyled
5. Go to any other page and click back to Cart internally using the Navbar and see that everything is fixed.
6. If you repeat this process when there's two separate items in the Cart you'll notice that only the first component has styling issues.

As mentioned everything works fine in development. In production all the styling works fine when using internal Nav links to the Cart (like from the Navbar). But refreshing the page messes up the styling just for the first component.

Here is an example of how the Cart SHOULD look like with two items:
[image: example]

Please let me know if you guys need more info on my end to help fix this issue. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you include the relevant part of `Cart.module.scss` (the part for `.item`)?

Comment: @machineghost Just added it. I have a separate module for CartItem which I included. Was the CartItem CSS supposed to be inside of the parent's CSS (Cart.module.scss). Or does it all get included in the same file in the end anyway? I'm relatively new to this stuff so I'm not sure what is appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to fix the problem. I wrapped the entire CartItem component's JSX inside a div that did NOT use a class that was specified in the CSS module. That solved the problem, but I'm not sure about the explanation why.

```
<div>
 {/* ...CartItem JSX */}
</div>
```